# Generate Schema XML returning headers only

Tags: json, xml, azure, bapi

I'm facing some issues when generating a schema using a RFC connection to SAP system while calling the function `BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GETLIST` which then creates a schema in my integration account using the content generated previously. However, after the schema is generated, when I access it all it has are the headers that are on the SAP table and none of its content. In this case the headers are `COMP_NAME` and `COMP_CODE` and it should return 122 rows but it does not and it also doesn't return any error so I cannot understand why it can retrieve the headers of the table but not its content.

I've tried enabling safe typing but after that the SAP connection doesn't work anymore, also tried calling different functions but the results are the same with different headers. Since this connector is recent I'm not able to find any solutions for this issue at this moment.

The flow first receives an HTTP Request, afterwards it calls the BAPI function to generate the schema which is then used to create the schema in the integration account with the following properties:

```
{
   "Content": "@{base64ToString(items('For_each')?['Content'])} ",
   "ContentType": "application/xml",
   "SchemaType": "Xml"
}
```

Comment: What kind of schema are you referring to? How do you generate it?

Comment: Using the activity "generate schema" from azure logic apps

Answer (score 0):

The schema is just that – the metadata describing the structure of an XML document. It is not the XML document itself.

The schema will contain two parts, the request message structure and the response message structure. You need to use the request message structure to form the BAPI get list, then can use the response message structure to parse the response. Either of the generic send message to SAP or the targeted Call BAPI actions of the SAP connector can be used to send the request message.